# Why SSH disconnect in seconds if I use proxy?

Tags: ssh, proxy

In macOS 10.12.6

When ssh to a server use the follow command:

```
ssh -i ~/key.pem ubuntu@123.111.222.101
```

the connection will keep until I disconnect it manually or the computer fall asleep.

However, when I ssh to the server behind a proxy:

```
ssh -i ~/key.pem -o ProxyCommand='/usr/bin/nc -x 127.0.0.1:1080 %h %p' ubuntu@123.111.222.101
```

the connection will disconnect if I don't type any word in the terminal after 30 seconds.

Why this will happen and how to keep the connection?

P.S.: the protocol of my proxy is socks5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this option. This should keep the connection open
`-o ServerAliveInterval=15`